# ClassNotFoundException when attempting to deploy a WAR file to Glassfish

Tags: java, deployment, ant, glassfish, war

As I continue to investigate using Ant Build Scripts, Spring and Glassfish I have run into another issue when deploying a WAR to Glassfish.

My build script seems to compile and produce a war file correctly, but when I come to deploy it using

```
<glassfish-deploy force="true" file="${dist.dir}/${name}.war" />
```

I get the following error message

```
[glassfish-deploy] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.crowderconsult.spider.controllers.HelloController. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Of which I belive the underlying issue is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.crowderconsult.spider.controllers.HelloController
```

However, the class that it can't find is one of the ones I have written and contained within the WAR file. I checked by opening the WAR with winzip and the classfile is within there.

Normally I would figure that I hadn't included something in the classpath, but 
1) the class is in the file I'm trying to deploy so would expect it to be on the classpath anyway and
2) I don't know how to set the classpath for glassfish's deploy command.

I've also tried to deploy it using the command line asadmin task, and the admin console of glassfish, with the same results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I feel like I'm just going round in circles?! If any other information is required please let me know

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "it's there", I interpret that to mean there's a `HelloController.class` in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder in the package path `uk.co.crowderconsult.spider.controllers`.  Is that true?  If yes, the class loader should find it.  If not, that would explain why you have the CNFE.

You are correct: if your WAR file is constructed properly, you shouldn't have to do anything else to explain CLASSPATH to the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the response
By "its there" inside the WAR object there are 3 folders, a META-INF, WEB-INF and one which maps to the package list uk.co etc. Within that folder there is a HelloController.class file. 
However, this is a separate folder, not under WEB-INF/classes, which suggests to me that I'm not creating the WAR file properly? I'm using the WAR ant task to build it, so I think I'll dig into that a bit further

Comment: Okay, it appears I was not creating the WAR correctly, I had not specified the classes nested element, so my java classes where not in the correct place. Adding this nested element resolves the issue and I've included the task below for information purposes.

'<war destfile="${dist.dir}/${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
   <classes dir="${build.dir}"/>
   <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.*" />
   </fileset>
  </war>'

Comment: My original answer is over nine years old.  Ask a new question.  The answer is obvious: the Oracle JDBC driver JAR is not in the WAR.  You have a packaging issue.  Open the WAR with zip or tar and inspect the contents.  Either the JAR isn't present or it's not part of the CLASSPATH.  Google for instructions on how to create a WAR file properly.